# Better ways to search files in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directory

I'm am writing a program to search files within a certain directory but seem to have some lag issues. The folder I'm searching has 500 files and around 1000 folders that hold these files.
There might be a folder within a folder(THE 2nd LEVEL).

I am using the lines below to grab all my files.

```
    string location =  "C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Documents\\PDFS";
    string[] PDFS = Directory.GetFiles(@location, "*pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

My current setup is MS Visual C# 2010 Express.

Comment: Did you try to go multithreading? Parallel.For(...)
The disk is only one, this can be a non-optimization, but trying worth the effort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) instead which uses lazy evaluation, so files are only brought into memory as you iterate over the results.

Comment: +1. Note that this assumes that GetFiles is the actual performance problem with your program (likely, but you should always measure to confirm performance issues).

Comment: Also it should be noted that the *same overall work* still has to be done (plus a little more overhead) - it is just not front-loaded as with `GetFiles()` but done over time as you iterate.